# Change encoding of DOM4J Document: UTF to ISO-8859-1 (Java)

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1, dom4j

I need to create an `org.dom4j.Document` but when I print it it's always `UTF-8`.

I want to change it to `ISO-8859-1` but I didn't find the way to do it.
It's not possible to use `.setEncoding()` and the Document is created on the fly (not reading from an `InputStream`).

It's the same problem that is discussed at http://www.coderanch.com/t/127978/XML/change-Encoding-Dom

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can set the encoding in the [OutputFormat](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/org/dom4j/io/OutputFormat.html) format class and use that to configure [XMLWriter](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/org/dom4j/io/XMLWriter.html).

```
OutputFormat outFormat = new OutputFormat();    
outFormat.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

XMLWriter out = new XMLWriter(outputStream, outFormat);
out.write(myDocumentObject);
```

You will need to provide the XMLWriter class an OutputStream or Writer.